# How can I get a (MM-DD-YYYY) format from a UTC string in javascript?

Tags: javascript, date, datetime, utc, toisostring

I am working with a Date object in a different timezone than the console. I'm using utc string to get the actual time that was logged in that timezone. Is there an easy way to extract the (MM-DD-YYYY) from the utc string than just substringing into the string?

```
isoString = "2016-08-25T15:17:21.033-10:00"
utc= (new Date(isoString)).toUTCString()
```

Returns: 
"Fri, 26 Aug 2016 01:17:21 GMT"

Would like (08-26-2016)

Comment: the `Date` object has no real string formatting options. you'll have to build it out of smaller parts, e.g. `.getMonth()`

Comment: aww man, thanks, that's what i thought

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date

Comment: With [momentjs](http://momentjs.com/) you can format the dates as you wish: `moment("2016-08-25T15:17:21.033-10:00").format('DD-MM-YYYY');`

Comment: The question is about is it possible to pass format toUTCString(). The linked question is about formatting general date, not converted to UTC

Answer (score 3):

You would convert it into a `Date` Object and then try out the methods available in it to get the required `format`.

```
var isoString = "2016-08-25T15:17:21.033-10:00"
var utc= (new Date(isoString)).toUTCString()

console.log(new Date(utc).getDate() + "-" + (new Date(utc).getMonth() + 1) +
                                                 "-" + new Date(utc).getFullYear());
```

Comment: `getDay()` returns the day of the week! [Docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/getDay)

Comment: Ah... in hurry.... sorry... changed it to getDate()... Thanks...

Comment: It worked. Thanks